# xib file button issues

Tags: swift, xib, uialertcontroller

I have a xib file which I have attached a button to it.  The xib is loaded into views on the storyboard and works perfectly.  All the button does at the moment is print to the console "button touched".

```
@IBAction func btnQuickMenuTouchUpInside(sender: UIButton) {

    println("button touched")

}
```

Ideally I would like a UIAlertController to pop up when I click the button as per the code below:

```
    var alert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: "Message", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Click", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
   self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

However, it complains that myMenuVC does not have a member named presentViewController.

Can anyone help explain how I get the UIAlertController to work from a button from a xib view?

Many thanks, Alan.

PS

Code for myMenuVC.swift as follows:

```
//
//  myMenuVC.swift
//  SwiftLoginScreen
//
//  Created by Alan Tingey on 29/04/2015.
//  Copyright (c) 2015 Alan Tingey. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

@IBDesignable class myMenuVC: UIView {

    var view:UIView!
    @IBOutlet var titleLabel: UILabel!

    @IBAction func btnQuickMenuTouchUpInside(sender: UIButton) {

        println("button touched")


        var alert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: "Message", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Click", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
       //self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)


    }
    override init(frame: CGRect)
    {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setup()
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)
    {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        setup()
    }

    func setup()
    {
        view = loadViewFromNib()
        view.frame = bounds
        // view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleHeight
        addSubview(view)
    }

    func loadViewFromNib() -> UIView
    {
        let bundle = NSBundle(forClass:self.dynamicType)
        let nib = UINib(nibName: "vwMyMenuVC", bundle: bundle)
        //let nib = UINib(nibName: "myMenuVC", bundle: bundle)
        let view = nib.instantiateWithOwner(self, options: nil)[0] as! UIView

        var myString:NSString = "straightRED"
        var myMutableString = NSMutableAttributedString()

        myMutableString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: myString as String, attributes: [NSFontAttributeName:UIFont(name: "Zapf Dingbats", size: 28.0)!])

        myMutableString.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: UIColor.redColor(), range: NSRange(location:8,length:3))

        // set label Attribute

        titleLabel.attributedText = myMutableString


        //let view = nib.instantiateWithOwner(self, options: nil)[0] as UIView

        return view
    }

}
```

Comment: And you are subclassing `UIViewController`?

Comment: I created a view on a storyboard and set its class to the myMenuVC.swift file which creates the top of the view from the vwMyMenuVC.xib file.  Is this called subclassing?  Apologies for not fully understanding the terminology.  I hope I have explained myself properly?

Comment: So if I understand you correctly you should be setting the `myMenuVC.swift` to the view controller in the storyboard where you load the nib and not to the nib file itself. Open `myMenuVC.swift` and check if it is subclassing `UIViewController` because it should be.

Comment: Sorry, I am unsure what this means.  I will add the code for the myMenuVC.swift to the question.  Thank you for your patience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`myMenuVC` is a `UIView` subclass, not a `UIViewController` subclass.

You can either create a new view controller and re-create this `UIView` interface on the view controller's view.

You can also present the alert controller on the application's root view controller from the `myMenuVC` `UIView` subclass directly:

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate?.window??.rootViewController?.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```